# Adding Labels to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online

I am working on ArcGIS Online.I want to add New Labels to seperate my fields.
The first image represents the original Fields.
[image]

The second image represents how I want it to be(Seperated with labels).

[image]

How can I add Labels to ArcGIS Online to seperate my fields?

Answer (score 2):

While I do not believe it is possible to add subsets of fields within the AGOL (ArcGIS Online) environment, a potential workaround is modifying the **alias** of each field participating in the label, e.g.

Label 1 Governate

Label 1 District

Label 1 Village_Town

Label 2 ID

If I misunderstood your question and you were looking to add additional fields e.g. Label 1, Label 2 in between your fields (in the order you showed in your second image) please respond and I can provide that info for you.